# illegal memory access : multi-thread with one GPU ( OpenCV3.1 + CUDA 8.0) (full code)

Tags: multithreading, opencv

What I want to do is just running 5 threads in one GTX1060 video card, but fail:
[running environment]:
Linux Ubuntu 16.04 + CUDA 8.0 + OpenCV3.1 + GTX1060

[Error]:

> OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (an illegal memory access was encountered)
>   in linesAccum_gpu, file
>   /home/weiran/DB_OpenCV/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaimgproc/src/cuda/hough_lines.cu,
>   line 143 OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (an illegal memory access was
>   encountered) in linesAccum_gpu, file
>   /home/weiran/DB_OpenCV/opencv-3.1.0/modules/cudaimgproc/src/cuda/hough_lines.cu,
>   line 143
>           terminate called recursively

[Code]:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudawarping.hpp"

#include "pthread.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::cuda;

#define PI 3.1415926
#define NUM_LOOP 500

void carReviseInterface_gpu(Mat src, Mat &dst)
{
        // Canny
        Mat contours;
        cuda::GpuMat d_src(src);
        //CannyDetect(src, contours);
        cuda::GpuMat gray_src;
        cv::cuda::cvtColor(d_src, gray_src, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        cuda::GpuMat d_contours;

        Ptr<cuda::CannyEdgeDetector> cuCanny = cuda::createCannyEdgeDetector(74, 147);
        cuCanny->detect(gray_src, d_contours);///

        //d_contours.download(contours);

        //imshow("1 gpu canny", contours);
        // 
        //std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
        //HoughLineDetect(src, lines);

        ///////////////////
        //GpuMat d_src(contours);
        GpuMat d_lines;
        {
                const int64 start = getTickCount();

                Ptr<cuda::HoughSegmentDetector> hough = cuda::createHoughSegmentDetector(1.0f, (float)(CV_PI / 180.0f), 129, 20);

                hough->detect(d_contours, d_lines);        // d_src

                const double timeSec = (getTickCount() - start) / getTickFrequency();
                //cout << "GPU Time : " << timeSec * 1000 << " ms" << endl;
                //cout << "GPU Found : " << d_lines.cols << endl;
        }
        vector<Vec4i> lines_gpu;
        if (!d_lines.empty())
        {
                lines_gpu.resize(d_lines.cols);
                Mat h_lines(1, d_lines.cols, CV_32SC4, &lines_gpu[0]);
                d_lines.download(h_lines);
        }

        //for (size_t i = 0; i < lines_gpu.size(); ++i)
        //{
        //        Vec4i l = lines_gpu[i];
        //        line(src, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, LINE_AA);
        //}

        //imshow("2 gpu hough ", src);


}


void *threadFun(void *arg)
{
    Mat src_gpu = imread("/home/weiran/DB_Multimedia/plate2.png");//plate2.png
    Mat res, res_gpu;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LOOP; ++i) {
        carReviseInterface_gpu(src_gpu, res_gpu);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t pth[5];
    memset(&pth, 0, sizeof(pth));
        Mat src = imread("/home/weiran/DB_Multimedia/plate2.png");//plate2.png
        Mat res, res_gpu;
        Mat src_gpu = src.clone();
        imshow("0 src", src);

        cv::Size size;
        size.width = 320;
        size.height = 240;


        const int64 start2 = getTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&pth[i], NULL, threadFun, NULL);
    }
//        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LOOP; ++i)
//        {
//                carReviseInterface_gpu(src_gpu, res_gpu);
//                //cuResize(src_gpu, res_gpu, size);
//        }
        const double timeSec2 = (getTickCount() - start2) / getTickFrequency();
        cout << "GPU Time : " << (timeSec2 * 1000) / NUM_LOOP << " ms" << endl;


        imshow("8 cpu src", src);
//        imshow("9 cpu res", res);

        imshow("8 gpu src", src_gpu);
//        imshow("9 gpu res", res_gpu);


        waitKey(0);
        return 0;
}
```

What should I do?
Thanks in advance for any help~

Comment: Some of the OpenCV GPU code is not re-entrant; I've been bitten by `FAST_GPU()` falling over when being called from two different threads. My solution was just a simple `std::lock_guard` before the calls. Hough and Canny probably both need guards, but simple APIs like `cvtColor()` don't.

Comment: I don't see any "CUDA programming" here. This looks like thread safety issues in OpenCV. Nothing to do with CUDA programming at all. And you are not running those threads on the GPU, you are running them on the host CPU

Comment: @Ken Y-N it works, Really appreciate your help！

Answer (score 0):

The key to multi threading in OpenCV is to use only GPU functions which take a [stream](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/df3/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1Stream.html) parameter.

```
cv::cuda::Stream myStream;
gpuImage.download(cpuImage, myStream);
```

OpenCV cuda functions which don't take a stream may have buffer overwrite issues when accessed from multiple threads.